# In a collision between two objects of different masses

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, collision

Suppose an object is travelling at a velocity it strikes another object of a different mass and comes to rest and the other object starts moving, would the two objects have the same kinetic energy before the first object came to rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For perfectly elastic collision both momentum and kinetic energy is conserved. That is how the final velocities of two masses are calculated.  If the first body comes to rest after collision then either both masses are same or there will be loss in kinetic energy ( maybe in the form of heat, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove it
By using conservation of momentum
M$v_{A}$=m$v_{B}$+M$v_{A'}$........ 1...since a comes to rest $v_{A'}$=0

To find kinetic energy

E$k_{initial}$=1/2M$v_{A}$^2

E$k_{final}$=1/2m$v_{b}$^2

Putting value from 1

E$k_{final}$=1/2$M^2$/m$v_{a}$^2

And this shows that kinetic energy isnt same note that if masses were same then kinetic energy would have been same